# Is Scala's collection.mutable.PriorityQueue thread safe?

Tags: scala, data-structures, concurrency

I am using a `PriorityQueue` across multiple threads. I am not sure it's a thread safe data-structure.

Is it safe to use `scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue` across multiple threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: It is not safe.

Let's have a look!  scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue [uses](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/PriorityQueue.scala#L61)

```
private val resarr = new ResizableArrayAccess[A]
```

where ResizableArrayAccess is [defined](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/PriorityQueue.scala#L51-L57) inside PriorityQueue as

```
private class ResizableArrayAccess[A] extends AbstractSeq[A] with ResizableArray[A] with Serializable {
```

From there, going to `scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray`, it is obvious that this is not thread safe, e.g. by looking at the [update](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ResizableArray.scala#L47-L50) method:

```
protected var array: Array[AnyRef] = new Array[AnyRef](math.max(initialSize, 1))
 // ... snip ... //
def update(idx: Int, elem: A) {
  if (idx >= size0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(idx.toString)
  array(idx) = elem.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
}
```

So we have unprotected access to a mutable var and usage of `scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue` from multiple Threads is not encouraged.

If you really need to use it from multiple threads *and concurrency is not important* you can use some meaning of synchronization, e.g. `scala.util.SyncVar` to protect against concurrency issues like race conditions.  Otherwise using another data structure is better.

Answer (score 4):

Mutable objects are by definition not thread safe, so I wouldn't consider anything from a package called *mutable* as thread safe. As it's been pointed out, `java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue` can be a good choice.

If you want to research into the Scala collections, `scala.collection.immutable.Queue` can be a good starting point. See the Queues section of the [Concrete Immutable Collection Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html#immutable_queues).

Comment: Mutable objects dan definitely be thread-safe. People have been doing it for years using locks. Granted, it is difficult and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Scala and Java collection classes are generally not thread-safe unless they explicitly say so in their docs. In this case I don't think `scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue` is thread-safe, try using `java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue` instead.